# PCRE not matching U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE

Tags: regex, pcre

Context: I’m trying to replace some HTML in an epub using Sigil (epub editor) which can do search/replace using PCRE.

The sequence I’m searching for contains a Narrow No-Break Space (Unicode 0x202f).  I’ve tried using   (the literal character), `\s`, `\p{Zs}`, `\p{Space_Separator}`, `\p{Z}`, `\p{Separator}` and `\x{202f}`.  The generic tokens match similar strings containing a regular space, but nothing seems to match this character.

I’m probably missing something obvious here, but I don’t know what.

I can ‘easily’ work around this (non-regex replace 0x202f with some other token first), but I’d like to know how to do this as it’s likely to come up again and if it’s a problem with the program it would be good to know I’m not doing something stupid before approaching the developers.

Comment: If these patterns do not work, it is not a PCRE engine. Well, you can also try `\x20`, `\xA0` (non-breaking space), `[[:space:]]`, but also make sure you actually have a space in the HTML, maybe there is something like `&nbsp;`? Then try `&nbsp;`.

Comment: If you use `\s` try with [`u` flag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php): [`preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', "a\xE2\x80\xAFb")`](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLKzU5I1@hoCg1Pb4otSAnMTlVQ10/plhbv1RdR0EdiJUSYypcjWIqLAxiKhzdkpQ0rf//BwA). If it's a html entity try either `&#8239;` or `&#x202f;` (in php you would decode entities using [html_entity_decode](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLS6W4pEjBVkE9UU3ZwsjY0jpJTbnCyMAozTpZ3ZqLKzU5I18hoyQ3Jz41rySzpDI@JTU5PyVVA6RL0/r/fwA)).

Comment: Sigil uses the PCRE2 library since two years at least, be sure to get the latest version. You can try this syntax with the unicode mode switched to on: `\N{U+202F}`. In practice, probably a Unicode checkbox somewhere, but if nothing to set on Unicode mode exists, you can try to start the pattern with `(*UTF)`.